Removing weightpaint does not remove objects
I'm using a geometry node to place a bunch of objects on my plane. However, whenever I erase some of the weight the objects remain. Anyone who might know why?




I think you're not decreasing it all the way to 0, just low enough that it seams to be the same as on the rest of the image.
